# PyQt: Change GUI Layout after button is clicked

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qmainwindow

Okay, I am jumping from Tkinter to PyQt, because PyQt is just so much more advanced, and nicer to work with. BUT! I am having some troubles here.

I am trying to change the GUI layout after I press one of my buttons on the main screen. I press the first button of the main GUI page, then I want it to go to another GUI page that I will create. I have been sitting here for hours trying to find some way to do this - no videos on YouTube, and I haven't found any stack-overflow pages that help. So I learnt that there is a Qt Designer program. I don't like programs like that, so please try to stay away from using that when answering.

PS: I don't want to be working with more than one .py file, but if there is no other way, I guess I'm going to have to do so.

Here is my code so far:

```
class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 400, 450)
        self.setFixedSize(400,450)
        self.setWindowTitle(" Tool")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('PhotoIcon.png'))
        self.home()

    def home(self):
        ToolsBTN = QtGui.QPushButton('text', self)
        ToolsBTN.clicked.connect(ToolTab)
        ToolsBTN.move(50, 350)
        CPSBTN = QtGui.QPushButton('text', self)
        CPSBTN.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
        CPSBTN.move(150, 350)
        CreatorBTN = QtGui.QPushButton('Creator', self)
        CreatorBTN.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
        CreatorBTN.move(250, 350)
        self.show()

class ToolTab(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__2(self):
        super(ToolTab, self).__init__2()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 400, 450)
        self.setFixedSize(400,450)
        self.setWindowTitle(" Tool")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('PhotoIcon.png'))
        self.Toolsgui()

    def Toolsgui(self):
        CPSBTN = QtGui.QPushButton('123', self)
        CPSBTN.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
        CPSBTN.move(150, 300)
        self.show()

def Run():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    GUITOOL = ToolTab()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

Run()
```

Comment: you doesn't change layout - you change windows. You close one window and open new window. Changing layout means you have only one window and you replace widgets inside this window.

Comment: Hey in the class `ToolTab` you are using `__init__2(*args)` as constructor. But will it still be the same as `__init__` constructor?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The solution I propose is based on the function `setupUi()` that generates Qt Designer, this is responsible for creating the internal elements of the window.

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QWidget
#For PyQt5 :
#from PyQt5.QWidgets import QApplication , QMainWindow , QPushButton , QWidget
class UIWindow(object):
    def setupUI(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setGeometry(50, 50, 400, 450)
        MainWindow.setFixedSize(400, 450)
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle("UIWindow")
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        # mainwindow.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('PhotoIcon.png'))
        self.ToolsBTN = QPushButton('text', self.centralwidget)
        self.ToolsBTN.move(50, 350)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)


class UIToolTab(object):
    def setupUI(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setGeometry(50, 50, 400, 450)
        MainWindow.setFixedSize(400, 450)
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle("UIToolTab")
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.CPSBTN = QPushButton("text2", self.centralwidget)
        self.CPSBTN.move(100, 350)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.uiWindow = UIWindow()
        self.uiToolTab = UIToolTab()
        self.startUIWindow()

    def startUIToolTab(self):
        self.uiToolTab.setupUI(self)
        self.uiToolTab.CPSBTN.clicked.connect(self.startUIWindow)
        self.show()

    def startUIWindow(self):
        self.uiWindow.setupUI(self)
        self.uiWindow.ToolsBTN.clicked.connect(self.startUIToolTab)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Start:**

[image]

**After button clicked:**

[image]

**After another button clicked:**

[image]

and more elegant solution:

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QWidget
#For PyQt5 :
#from PyQt5.QWidgets import QApplication , QMainWindow , QPushButton , QWidget

class UIWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(UIWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        # mainwindow.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('PhotoIcon.png'))
        self.ToolsBTN = QPushButton('text', self)
        self.ToolsBTN.move(50, 350)


class UIToolTab(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(UIToolTab, self).__init__(parent)
        self.CPSBTN = QPushButton("text2", self)
        self.CPSBTN.move(100, 350)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 400, 450)
        self.setFixedSize(400, 450)
        self.startUIToolTab()

    def startUIToolTab(self):
        self.ToolTab = UIToolTab(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("UIToolTab")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.ToolTab)
        self.ToolTab.CPSBTN.clicked.connect(self.startUIWindow)
        self.show()

    def startUIWindow(self):
        self.Window = UIWindow(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("UIWindow")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.Window)
        self.Window.ToolsBTN.clicked.connect(self.startUIToolTab)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you so much but for some reason the icon string is not working for me i have tryed to change it around quit abit but still nothing think yoiu could help out there agian?

Comment: @Kliffy Use MainWindow.setWindowIcon(QIcon({path of image})) in UIToolTab and UIWindow

Comment: When i do that i get this error " QWidget.setWindowIcon(QIcon): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QWidget' " and when i add Qwidget to the line im give "  type object 'MainWindow' has no attribute 'QWidget' "

Comment: Thank You very much @eyllanesc! this solution helped me as well.

Comment: How do I change it to display a textbox after the button is clicked?