# Create a full Screen Button in PYQT5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, fullscreen

Start of the application

[image]

Plot the Graph

[image]

Full Screen

[image]

I have an application with 4 Box on the main window, and I want to had a full screen button in a windows which plot some graph, like on the Pictures on the top.

I first try a method to creating a fullScreen function in my code, linked to the button, but it is no work.

Here is my try :

```
class mainApplication(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(mainApplication, self).__init__(parent)

        self.layoutMap = {}
        self.buttonMap = {}

        # Figure Bottom Right
        self.figure = plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
        self.figure.set_facecolor('0.915')
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure) 

        # Main Figure
        self.setGeometry(600, 300, 1000, 600)

        self.topLeft()
        self.topRight()
        self.bottomLeft()
        self.bottomRight()

        mainLayout = QGridLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.topLeftBox, 1, 0)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.topRightBox, 1, 1)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.bottomLeftBox, 2, 0)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.bottomRightBox, 2, 1)
        mainLayout.setRowStretch(1, 1)
        mainLayout.setRowStretch(2, 1)
        mainLayout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        mainLayout.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
        self.saveLayout(mainLayout, "main")

        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        self.setWindowTitle("Title")
        QApplication.setStyle("Fusion")
        self.show()

    def bottomRight(self):

        self.bottomRightBox = QGroupBox("Bottom Right")

        # Create Select Button
        chooseButton = QPushButton("Select")
        chooseButton.setMaximumWidth(100)
        chooseButton.setMaximumHeight(20)
        self.saveButton(chooseButton)
        chooseButton.clicked.connect(self.selectFunction)

        # Create Full Screen Button
        fullScreenButton = QPushButton("Full")
        fullScreenButton.setMaximumWidth(100)
        fullScreenButton.setMaximumHeight(20)
        self.saveButton(fullScreenButton)
        fullScreenButton.clicked.connect(self.swichFullScreen)

        # Create Layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        layout.addWidget(chooseButton)
        layout.addWidget(fullScreenButton)
        layout.addStretch(1)

        self.saveLayout(layout, "full")


        # Add Layout to GroupBox
        self.bottomRightBox.setLayout(layout)   


    def selectFunction(self):

        # Select Data
        filePath, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', '/Data/')
        df = pd.read_csv(str(filePath))
        x = df.x.tolist()
        y = df.y.tolist()

        # Create Figure
        self.figure.clf()
        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        ax.plot(x, y)
        ax.set_facecolor('0.915')
        ax.set_title('Graphique')

        # Draw Graph
        self.canvas.draw()

    def saveLayout(self,obj, text):
         self.layoutMap[text] = obj

    def findLayout(self,text):
         return self.layoutMap[text]

    def saveButton(self,obj):
         self.buttonMap[obj.text()] = obj

    def findButton(self,text):
         return self.buttonMap[text]


    def swichFullScreen(self):
        self.setLayout(self.findLayout("full"))
        self.show()





if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = mainApplication()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Have you an idea? because for example, if in my initialization I don't do :

```
self.setLayout(mainLayout)
```

but :

```
swichFullScreen()
```

I have the result that I want, so why call this fonction after the creation of my main layout don't work?

Moreover, I have try an other thing adapter from this : [PyQt: Change GUI Layout after button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41290035/pyqt-change-gui-layout-after-button-is-clicked)

But it still not worked because when I clic on the button "full", it switch very well, but the normalWindow object has been delete so the button select stop to work.

If you have a solution for my first idea, I prefer because it avoid the creation of other class, but if it is not possible and that you find a solution for the second solution to avoid the destruction of the object, I take it too.

Here the code for my second solution :

```
class fullScreenApplication(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(fullScreenApplication, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(600, 300, 1000, 600)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(600, 300, 1000, 600)
        self.normalWindows()

    def normalWindows(self):
        self.normalBox = mainApplication(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.normalBox)
        self.normalBox.findButton("Full").clicked.connect(self.fullScreenWindow)
        self.show()

    def fullScreenWindow(self):
        self.FullBox = fullScreenApplication(self)
        self.FullBox.setLayout(self.normalBox.findLayout("full"))
        self.normalBox.findButton("Full").clicked.connect(self.normalWindows)
        self.normalBox.findButton("Select").clicked.connect(self.normalBox.selectFunction)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.FullBox)
        self.show()





if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot  as plt
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class mainApplication(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(mainApplication, self).__init__(parent)

        self.layoutMap = {}
        self.buttonMap = {}

        # Figure Bottom Right
        self.figure = plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
        self.figure.set_facecolor('0.915')
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure) 

        # Main Figure
#        self.setGeometry(600, 300, 1000, 600)

        self.topLeftBox    = self.topLeft()
        self.topRightBox   = self.topRight()
        self.bottomLeftBox = self.bottomLeft()
        self.bottomRight()

        self.mainLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.topLeftBox, 1, 0)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.topRightBox, 1, 1)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.bottomLeftBox, 2, 0)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.bottomRightBox, 2, 1)
        self.mainLayout.setRowStretch(1, 1)
        self.mainLayout.setRowStretch(2, 1)
        self.mainLayout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        self.mainLayout.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
        self.saveLayout(self.mainLayout, "main")

        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

        self.setWindowTitle("Title")
        QApplication.setStyle("Fusion")
#        self.show()

    def bottomRight(self):

        self.bottomRightBox = QGroupBox("Bottom Right")

        # Create Select Button
        chooseButton = QPushButton("Select")
        chooseButton.setMaximumWidth(100)
        chooseButton.setMaximumHeight(20)
        self.saveButton(chooseButton)
        chooseButton.clicked.connect(self.selectFunction)

        # Create Full Screen Button
        self.fullScreenButton = QPushButton("Full")
        self.fullScreenButton.setMaximumWidth(100)
        self.fullScreenButton.setMaximumHeight(20)
        self.saveButton(self.fullScreenButton)
        self.fullScreenButton.clicked.connect(self.swichFullScreen)

        # Create Layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        layout.addWidget(chooseButton)
        layout.addWidget(self.fullScreenButton)
        layout.addStretch(1)

        self.saveLayout(layout, "full")


        # Add Layout to GroupBox
        self.bottomRightBox.setLayout(layout)   


    def selectFunction(self):

        # Select Data
        filePath, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', '/Data/')
        df = pd.read_csv(str(filePath))
        x = df.x.tolist()
        y = df.y.tolist()

        # Create Figure
        self.figure.clf()
        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        ax.plot(x, y)
        ax.set_facecolor('0.915')
        ax.set_title('Graphique')

        # Draw Graph
        self.canvas.draw()

    def saveLayout(self,obj, text):
         self.layoutMap[text] = obj

    def findLayout(self,text):
         return self.layoutMap[text]

    def saveButton(self,obj):
         self.buttonMap[obj.text()] = obj

    def findButton(self,text):
         return self.buttonMap[text]


    def swichFullScreen(self):
#        self.setLayout(self.findLayout("full"))           # ---
#        self.show()                                       # ---
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        if self.sender().text()== "Full":
            self.topLeftBox.hide()
            self.topRightBox.hide()
            self.bottomLeftBox.hide()
            self.bottomRightBox.hide()
            self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.bottomRightBox, 0, 0, 1, 2)
            self.bottomRightBox.show()
            self.fullScreenButton.setText("NoFull")

        else:
            self.bottomRightBox.hide()
            self.topLeftBox.show()
            self.topRightBox.show()
            self.bottomLeftBox.show()
            self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.bottomRightBox, 2, 1)
            self.bottomRightBox.show()
            self.fullScreenButton.setText("Full")            

    def topLeft(self):
        textEdit = QTextEdit()
        return textEdit
    def topRight(self):
        textEdit = QTextEdit()
        return textEdit
    def bottomLeft(self):
        textEdit = QTextEdit()
        return textEdit
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = mainApplication()
    mainWindow.setGeometry(200, 100, 1000, 600)  
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: @kilag If my example helped you, remember to mark it as correct.

Comment: kindly avoid wildcard imports, not helpful at all when debugging.